# select some custom columns from more than one table by user selection in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to select some custom columns from more than one table by user selection.
(I made a form with checkboxes. The user selects what he needs and I don't know what to do next)

or 
is it possible to `select * from more than one table` by this form??

Comment: Your question is very broad and therefore difficult to provide a helpful answer without additional information about your form layout, table structure and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION/ALL

```
sql = "Select * from table1 UNION ALL Select * from table2 UNION ALL Select * from table3"
```

Comment: this query is select all data from table with same columns